# how to deserialize a python printed dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, deserialization

I have python's str dictionary representations in a database as varchars, and I want to retrieve the original python dictionaries

How to have a dictionary again, based in the str representation of a dictionay?

### Example

```
>>> dic = {u'key-a':u'val-a', "key-b":"val-b"}
>>> dicstr = str(dic)
>>> dicstr
"{'key-b': 'val-b', u'key-a': u'val-a'}"
```

In the example would be turning dicstr back into a usable python dictionary.

Comment: BTW are they Python dictionaries or JSON objects? Easy to confuse the two :)

Comment: Python dictionaries. I think json doesn't allow the `u'sth'` syntax (looking at the `u` from unicode)

Comment: Nope, but I cannot see your real data, can I? JSON ends up considerably more often in databases than Python `repr`-encoded objects, so I thought I'd point that out just in case.

Comment: If that's your database, you might want to consider using the `pickle` module instead of `repr` (unless you want the data human-readable too).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval()` and for such cases prefer `repr()` over `str()`, as `str()` doesn't guarantee that the string can be converted back to useful object.

```
In [7]: import ast

In [10]: dic = {u'key-a':u'val-a', "key-b":"val-b"}

In [11]: strs = repr(dic)

In [12]: strs
Out[12]: "{'key-b': 'val-b', u'key-a': u'val-a'}"

In [13]: ast.literal_eval(strs)
Out[13]: {u'key-a': u'val-a', 'key-b': 'val-b'}
```

Comment: Does repr guarantee the backconversion? With numpy array in the dict it doesnt work.

Comment: Does this not seem like an unsafe answer to anyone else?? Don't eval strings use the `json` package.

Comment: @johnsimer Answer is using [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) not `eval()` and OPs string is not JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval()` or `ast.literal_eval()`. Most `repr()` strings can be evaluated back into the original object:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("{'key-b': 'val-b', u'key-a': u'val-a'}")
{'key-b': 'val-b', u'key-a': u'val-a'}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ast.literal_eval` could be the way to do it for simple dicts, BUT you should probably rethink your design and NOT save such text in database at first place. e.g.

```
import collections
d = {'a':1, 'b': collections.defaultdict()}

import ast
print ast.literal_eval(repr(d))
```

This will not work and throw `ValueError('malformed string')` basically you won't be convert back dict if it contains any non basic types.

**Better way** is to dump dict using pickle or json or something like that e.g.

```
import collections
d = {'a':1, 'b': collections.defaultdict()}

import json
print json.loads(json.dumps(d))
```

**Summary**: serialize using `repr`, deserialize using `ast.literal_eval` is BAD, serialize using `json.dumps` and deserialize using `json.loads` is GOOD

Comment: I think modules like `shelve` and `pickle` are also good for storing python objects.

Comment: I didn't say this before, but the data looks like the one that I posted, there are only dictionaries with values of unicode and str.

Comment: Eventually, I'll do it like you say in your summary. Thank you very much!