# is there any template tag in django to make ast.literal_eval?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there any template tag or workaround in django to make `ast.literal_eval(some_str)` in a template?

shoud I create a new template tag to do that? In this case, how would be that template tag?

The reason why I'm asking can be found here [how to deserialize a python printed dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165479/how-to-deserialize-a-python-printed-dictionary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No

Why would there be such a specific tag and why it would be used?

You can add one easily

```
# file: literal_eval.py

import ast

def literal_eval(value):
    return ast.literal_eval(value)

from django import template
register = template.Library()
register.filter('literal_eval', literal_eval)
```

and you can use it like this in template

```
{% load literal_eval %}

{{ some_str|literal_eval }}
```

now that leads to the question **"Why?"** what you will do with this?

**Edit**: OP said "he wants to deserialize some python dict saved as varchar", in that case template is not the place to do it, first convert text to dict and then pass it to template.

and better still rethink what is being done, saving dict `repr` is not the way to serialize and using `literal_eval` is not the way to de-serialize dicts, use `json.dumps` or such format to put dict into database and use `json.loads` to convert it back to dict. You can use pickle also but I would not recommend it.

Comment: asked your question in my question

Comment: sorry, I said something stupid :) This is the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165479/how-to-deserialize-a-python-printed-dictionary

Comment: @jperelli you are not doing it the right way, you should not be doing this in template

Comment: Ok, thank you all. I'm just working with this database, and this is how the data was stored (it's awful, but I received like that, and have to work with it). I'll try to "refactor" the data in order to be JSON or BSON.